How to call glTexImage2D properly using GLFW in C#
I was trying to set up texture rendering for an OpenGL project I was working on and I can't get it to work because apparently the glTexImage2D function's last parameter in a nint. I looked online and it appears to be a type of integer, but it doesn't make sense because that is the parameter that is supposed to be taking image data? Anyway, I'm trying to find a way to convert a byte array of RGBA data to this nint type to pass it to this function, does anyone know how?
This is the code so far:
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes("Grass_Block_29_JE2_BE2.rgba");
for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++) {

    Console.WriteLine(buffer[i]);

}

    while (!Glfw.WindowShouldClose(window)) {

        // Load texture
        uint texture = glGenTexture();
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
         glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        // Texture setup
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 160, 160, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer); // This is the code that isn't working, compiler says buffer is a byte[] not nint


I found the answer: It wants a reference so put &buffer instead of buffer.
